# How to tell if document.save is in progress in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm looking for a way to check if the document is already saving without `try {document.save()} catch (e) {if (e.name == 'ParallelSaveError') {...}}` but some quick googling didn't find such a thing.

(Mongoose version 5.7.3, fwiw)

**Context, because I feel like I may be at risk of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem):**

I'm wanting to avoid `ParallelSaveError` when updating the same object from different endpoints, and for various reasons I'm using a cached object. I'm thinking of writing a `saveDebounce` function that basically does the following:

- if already saving, wait until saved then save again
- wait X ms, then save
- (unless saveDebounce called in the meantime, in which case reset timer)

Am I totally crazy? Would a much saner solution involve not using a cache in this way, and or using `Model.update(...)` instead of `document.save()`?

(It is, for what it's worth, somewhat hard to use `Model.update` here, because I'm not just overwriting the data but needing to merge it as well, but I guess I could fetch lean, create merged version, then update the object in db, then refresh the cache with that updated version...)

Comment: Hm, my current solution (on a totally different level of abstraction) appears to be just returning 503 if I get a parallel save error, then using my sync library on the frontend to retry.

Comment: Damn, coming across my own post over a year later. Still don't have an adequate solution to this problem, and still basically considering the options above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this is what I've gone with. Shorter debounce times seemed too quick. I'm not using this everywhere, but in the main places that are likely to be called in parallel with something else, such as endpoints associated with frontend actions that often cause multiple `PUT` requests at essentially the same time.

Seems to work quite well and lets me use all of my original `pre validate` & `pre save` hooks. I'll update this post if it turns out to be a disaster

```js
UserSchema.methods.saveWithRetriesForParallelism = async function () {
  if (arguments.length) {throw new Error("Warning: saveWithRetriesForParallelism doesn't support callbacks")}
  const user = this
  const nRetries = 5
  let debounceTime = 100
  try {
    return await user.save()
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.name !== 'ParallelSaveError') {
      throw err
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < nRetries; i++) {
      console.log("ParallelSaveError - retry in " + debounceTime)
      await cu.waitNmillis(debounceTime)
      try {
        return await user.save()
      } catch (err2) {
        if (err.name !== 'ParallelSaveError') {
          throw err2
        }
        debounceTime*=2
      }
    }
    throw err
  }
}
```

Comment: (Just made a slight update due to a tiny disaster caused by one place in which I was using this method as if it supported callbacks, _which it does not._ You can rewrite it to do so but my solution is just to tell that to completely fail, since I'm using promises almost everywhere.)